# Checking For Overlapping Numeric Values In A List?

Tags: vb.net

I have a function that adds a new price rule, each price rule has two ranges (A_Low, A_High) (B_Low, B_High). When the functions wants to add a new price, it needs to make sure that the ranges do not overlap such that each inputted A and B value can only match 1 said price rule. A & B can be positive or negative numbers.

An example of logic:

Rule 1: A_Low = 0.0, A_High = 1.0; B_Low 0.0, B_High = 0.25

If i try to add the following rules:

Case 1: A_Low = 0.5, A_High = 1.5; B_Low 0.26, B_High = 1.0

The above test case should be allowed, such that A can overlap if B does not, B can overlap if A does not. I'm having an issue wrapping my head around the correct logic to evaluate and determine if the price rule I am trying to add is valid... I Know there are functions for checking overlapping dates, is there one for overlapping numeric ranges?

I Still cant figure out what i have wrong, here is my sample code:

```
 For Each p In Rules
        If p.A_Max > A_Min And p.A_Min < A_Max Then
            If p.B_Max> B_Min And p.B_Min < B_Max Then
                Return False
            End If
        End If

        If p.B_Max> B_Min And p.B_Min < B_Max Then
            If p.A_Max > A_Min And p.A_Min < A_Max Then
                Return False
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that can help: An [intervals collection class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37729/inserting-interval-into-a-collection/37938#37938).  It's written in C# but the coding is very straight forward and quite easy to follow.  It should be relatively simple to adapt to your needs.

Comment: If you're not familiar with c# too, there's a number of c# to vb.net or vice versa code parsers that will convert the block of code for you....a simple google search should pull a good number of them.

Answer (score 0):

This will return true if there's an overlap

Rule_High > Case_Low And Rule_Low < Case_High

You just need to check A and B and if both overlap then you have an error.

This also detect an overlap if you have something like this:

Case 1: A_Low = 0.5, A_High = 0.7; B_Low -1, B_High = 2